# My code in adding condition of range 1 - 9999 is not working using switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

So I created LeapYearCal this on If else statement I learn switch statement I want to recreate it using switch.
Somehow my condition for leap is working, but I want to add condition like value must be in 1- 9999 only else it'll returned false. but when my code is incorrect How do I solve the problem?

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
    switch ( year % 4)
    {
        case 0:
            if (year % 100 == 0)
            {
                    if ( (year % 400 == 0) )
                    {
                       if (year > 0)
                       {
                            if (year <= 9999)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                             else
                                return false;
                       }
                       else
                           return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        default:
             break;
    }
    return false;
```

I want to the output "True" if the year is Leap year and it's range 1-9999 else "False" if it is not in range regardless if its leap year

Comment: first of all, clean up your code. there are way too many returns and blocks in there. secondly, re-check your logic. third: what input did you enter, and which output did you expect/get?

Comment: Where does it fail?

Comment: IMO, that is not a good use case for learning switch.

Comment: There is a `return true`  where you did not check the 1-9999 range. Check the range at the beginning.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher thanks for telling that, a switch with 1 case is senseless, and also 1-9999 cases would not be great to write down.

Comment: Lol, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Isn't that a little too early?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm newbie on programming. I want to output my code where the value stored in my parameter is less than 0 / greater than 9999 the output must be false regardless if its a leap year. Somehow when I store for example -2020 it output True

Comment: @TaslimOseni no. this would be a terrific task to unit test, since every possible value can be evaluated without the code to a leap year or not. the rules for a leap year are quite simple

Comment: I did it on if else , but I just want it to recreate it using switch so what is the correct code for it ?

Comment: @ArielTabuzoJr. there are two locations where true is returned. Try your code by hand looking what is executed

Comment: @ArielTabuzoJr. just a remark: more code doesn't equal better. I just created an isLeapYear check here, took me less then 10 lines of code (in which there were blank lines)

Comment: @ArielTabuzoJr. this is not good to do with switch case. if else remains easier here, you just made it way more complicated than it has to be

Comment: @ArielTabuzoJr. Calm down, this is actually not a good way to learn how to use switch statements. But nevertheless, you can still try optimizing this code, there are way too many return statements. You can use the `&&` and `||` operators to your advantage.

Comment: @TaslimOseni No (and there is no need to laugh in a learning situation).  Writing test cases make logic clearer for the learner ("What do I need to know?") instead of just random runs.

Comment: I wasn't "laughing", (apologies if I didn't express myself properly). I initially thought it would be a bit of a herculean situation for OP to learn testing at this stage but I get your point now and I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Using switch-case statement in this use-case is inappropriate. This solution is based on [this code](https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-test-year-leap-year/) :

```java
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        boolean flag = false;
        if (year > 0 && year < 10000) 
        {
            flag = false;
        } 
        else if(year % 400 == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (year % 100 == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        else if(year % 4 == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: OP explicitly said the intention is **to use a switch statement**.

Comment: @Cheaker just a remark: instead of all those: flag = ... statements, replace them by: return <value>. You won't need the if's, you won't need the additional return statement. Also, have year % 4 != 0 in your first if condition, since any leap year is divisible by 4

Comment: @TaslimOseni there is no point in using switch statement here. Even if you use it here, it is just bad practice.